# Função para Tooltip não funciona ao executar uma segunda vez

Tags: javascript, funções, tooltip

Estou criando um esqueminha de tooltips, para que, ao clicar em determinado span, esse span mostre uma mensagem

HTML

```
<div class="banner-tooltips" id="banner-tooltips">
    <span id="primeira-tooltip">1°</span>
    <span id="segunda-tooltip">2°</span>
    <span id="terceira-tooltip">3°</span>
    <span id="quarta-tooltip">4°</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
function tooltips(){
    var caixaTooltips=document.getElementById("banner-tooltips");
    var tooltips=caixaTooltips.querySelectorAll("span");
    for(var i=0;i<tooltips.length;i++){
        tooltips[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
            var anterior=document.getElementsByClassName("banner-tooltip-active");
            console.log(anterior);
            if(anterior.length!=0){
                console.log(anterior);
                anterior.classList.remove("banner-tooltip-active");
            }
            console.log(anterior);
            this.classList.add("banner-tooltip-active");
        });
    }
}
tooltips();
```

Ao clicar na primeira tooltip, ele abre numa boa, porém, ao clicar uma segunda vez, ele diz que não é possível remover a classe de undefined. Por que isso ocorre, e como posso resolver o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente no primeiro `click` não tem nenhum elemento com a classe `banner-tooltip-active`, mas no segundo sim, e esse erro é gerado porque `document.getElementsByClassName("banner-tooltip-active");` vai retornar um *array*, então `anterior.classList` não vai funcionar. Sugiro alterar esse trecho:

```
if(anterior.length){
    for (let i = 0 ; i < anterior.length ; i++){
        anterior[i].classList.remove("banner-tooltip-active");
    }
}
```

Dessa forma ele irá iterar todos os outros `span` removendo o estilo ativo, e por fim habilitar só ao que foi clicado.

Comment: você sabe me dizer, como posso fazer para que, ao clicar fora da caixa principal, ele remova todas as classes "banner-tooltip-active" dos spans filhos ?

Comment: Sim @MuriloGambôa, é uma dúvida boa, fica melhor em um outro tópico =]

Comment: Já criei aheuhae :D